# Narrator for Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, narrator

Does anyone know if there is a reader (text-to-speech) tool for cygwin or linux?  I know of Microsoft's narrator, which partially works by sounding out what I type in the cygwin window (bash command line) but it doesn't report anything written to stdout.

Is there a native Cygwin tool anyone knows of?

Comment: Google **Linux text to speech**. I'd recommend "festival" or the alike, as they are quite simple to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BRLTTY](http://mielke.cc/brltty), which is available through Cygwin's setup.exe, apparently does have some speech support in addition to being able to drive Braille displays. I've got no experience with it though.

Answer (score 0):

BRLTTY seems to be just an interface for Braile displays - I couldn't make it "talk".

Instead get festival binary from bottom of [here](http://www.eguidedog.net/doc_build_win_festival.php), put it in C:/festival, and in cygwin

`echo "hello world" | /cygdrive/c/festival/bin/festival.exe --tts`

should say hello world. Then I put it into a script say.sh and calling

`~/say.sh hi`

actually does what you'd expect :)